# php write files path to array and use it in jQuery

Tags: php

I would like to iterate through folders and write all the `.jpg` files to a array in order to use them in the next step to create a time-lapse slideshow.

Below is the code that I already have, but how can I :

1. Write the `$file` to a array?
2. Access it from `jQuery` for later processing?

My code so far:

```
<?php
$dir ="files";
$i=0;
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dir)
);
$jpg_files = new RegexIterator($iterator, '/\.jpg$/'); // Dateiendung ".jpg"

foreach ($jpg_files as $file) {
    if (!$file->isFile()) {
        continue;
    }
    # echo $file->getPathname() . "\n";
    ?>
            <img src="<?php echo $file;?>"/>
    <?php
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your loop, instead of outputting the file with `<img src="<?php echo $file;?>"/>`, append it to an array:

```
foreach ($jpg_files as $file) {
    if (!$file->isFile()) {
        continue;
    }
    $files[] = "$file";            // appends to $files array
}
```

You can use `json_encode` to convert the array to a format JQuery can use. There are [various ways to get it into your JS environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740548/how-to-pass-variables-and-data-from-php-to-javascript). One way:

```
echo '<script> var files = ' . json_encode($files) . '</script>';
```